# Good Ui Toolkit For .net/mono

Tags: .net, user-interface, mono, cross-platform

What is the best toolkit for .NET/Mono. As i know, winforms or GTK# are not the best choice for a cross-platform applications. I would like something that can be distributed with the application, without any need to a runtime installtion beside mono on POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to choose 1 toolkit to use on all platforms, use Gtk#.

Otherwise use Gtk# for Linux, Windows.Forms for Windows, and MonoMac for OSX.

Comment: The problem with GTK# for me is, it is needed to be installed on Windows. Making one UI for specific platform seems to be the only option for now, but with the latest news about mono, maybe i will just go over to some other technology for cross-platform development.

Comment: GTK# has a redistributable installer for windows and OSX, you can include that with your own installer.

Comment: Out of curiosity why not WPF on Windows?

Comment: ...or WPF if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

There's [Eto.Forms](https://github.com/picoe/Eto) (on github), which is an abstraction layer on top of **WPF**, **WinForms**, **GTK**, and **MonoMac/Cocoa** - so you can get a native UI on all platforms without having to re-implement for each platform.  You don't have to suffer from lowest common denominator, since you can implement specifics for each platform (if desired, but not required).

It has an advantage that it is pure .NET and only relies on OS-supplied dependencies, as opposed to using GTK# where you'd have to bundle the native binaries for various platforms.